# Installing 1.9.1.0 problem, can't change language

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, install

Trying yo install 1.9.1.0 on Ubunto 14.04 server, can't change the installation language, when setting to Portugues(Brasil) the browser resets option to English.

Answer (score 1):

Open your app/locale directory. The most probably you have only en_US folder. You need to download your localization and put it in that folder.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-community-modules-portuguese-brazil-language-pack.html

This localization is for magento 1.6
http://freegento.com/magento-extensions/Locale_Mage_community_pt_BR-1.3.0.0.2.tgz